# Can you create a select menu that contains all values in a certain column?

Tags: javascript, ajax, searchkit, formbuilder

Is there a way in afform/Form Builder to create a select menu that contains all values in a specified column? An example would be **First Name**. I know that afform offers search fields, but these are generally based on how a Contact Field is set up. Since First Name is an open text field, the search field in afform will be an open text search. I am wanting to create a select menu that will synthesize all of the data in the **First Name** column and list them as options in the menu.

Comment: so it would have a list like: Anna, Albert, Barbara, Bob etc (and there may be 7 Bob's and 4 Anna's but the list will only show 1?)

Comment: Correct. And once I selected Bob from that list and it would return all contact in the table with First Name = Bob.

Comment: so in the sequel sense 'group by'. sorry i have no idea. was just trying to help elucidate the requirement in hope others can answer it.

Comment: So like when you add a filter on a spreadsheet - the unique values in the column are presented as a select list.  I don't know how/if that can be done currently but would be a nice addition.